# got APPT2 error after adding new material design dependencies

Tags: android-studio, material-design

I tried to add new material design to my android project with given line in material.io website :

```
compile 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

before that I added :

```
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
```

and after sync I got :

```
AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

[Image from error and dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur2RF.jpg)

logs not helping too .

anyone knows the correct address or it is too soon to use new material design?

Comment: I think you need to shift to androidx qualifiers as well as use the canary version of android studio so you can get the latest gradle plugin which has been upgraded. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html?__s=22ebtkjr9cx2eciqvece